# Prove knowledge of signature on committed value

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

Assume that a prover $P$, has previously obtained a signature $\sigma$ on a value $x$ from a verifier $V$. At a later stage, $P$ produces a Pedersen commitment $C$, to this value:

$C = g^x h^r$

I'm looking for a construction where $P$ can prove to $V$, in zero-knowledge, that they know that $C$ has been opened as well that a signature has been verified on that value, without revealing the signature.

I can find such a construction in [Efficient Protocols for Set Membership and Range Proofs](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-89255-7_15), but it uses bilinear-pairings, which I hope to avoid.

Is there such a construction available which is based on standard EC or modular groups?

Comment: In e.g. ECDSA signatures are randomized, so what exactly is against leaking the signature? Are you afraid that the data can be verified at a later date/time?

Comment: Note that "it" has gone to "he" to gender neutral *singular* "they". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: My problem is privacy. I cannot have the signature linkable to the user.